# rows of pascals triangle as powers of 11 in different numeral systems

Tags: binomial-coefficients, number-systems

It's not too difficult to see that (and understand why) in a base n system the ciphers of $(11_n)^k$ are equivalent to the k-th (0-indexed) row of pascals triangle until one of the numbers becomes greater than or equal to the base and thereby changing number represented by the next cipher.

Would something like $(11_\infty)^i$ or $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (11_n)^k$

1. make sense at all?
2. indeed represent the k-th row of pascals triangle?